# Laravel deleted event on mass delete for logging

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use spatie activity log for a model which is working fine for creating and updating events, but not for deleted events.

after some googling, i got the following

```
When executing a mass delete statement via Eloquent, the deleting and deleted model events will not be dispatched for the deleted models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when executing the delete statement.
```

is there any workaround to mass delete the selected items while dispatching the events so ActivityLog can pick it up ? other than doing it manually by looping through the selected items and deleting them or loop through them and adding log activity for each manuly.

```
// Delete all selected units that are not in the parentsIds array
    Unit::whereIn('id',$this->selected)->whereNotIn('id',$this->parentsIds)->delete();
```

and this is the model

```
// Activity Logging
protected static $recordEvents = ['deleted', 'updated', 'created'];
use LogsActivity;
public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
{
    return LogOptions::defaults()
    ->logOnly(['name', 'type','Parent.name']);
    // Chain fluent methods for configuration options
}
```

Comment: for the Model event to be fired `delete` has to be called on a model instance, a direct delete query won't do it ... there is no way for you to even know what records were actually deleted when doing the delete query

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the Model Instance

```
$unitsToDelete = Unit::whereIn('id',$this->selected)->whereNotIn('id',$this->parentsIds)
```

Then with a loop call delete method for each record

`foreach($unitsToDelete as $unit) {Unit::find($unit->id)->delete()}`

Not better and elegant way, but a workaround that solve the problem